# Suppressing -Wunused-value with gcc

Tags: c, gcc

Considering this piece of code:

```
#define STC_ASSERT(X,Msg) \
     (!!sizeof(struct{char STC_ASSERT;_Static_assert((X),Msg "");}))
#define A 43
#define B 42
#define C (STC_ASSERT(A-B>=0,"")?(A-B):0)
enum { c = C };
int main()
{
    STC_ASSERT(1,""); //can this not generate a warning on gcc?
}
```

Is there anything I can do *inside* the `STC_ASSERT` `_Static_assert` wrapper to prevent the line in `main` from generating an `-Wunused-value` warning when compiling with `gcc -Wall -Wextra`?

(`_Pragma` with `GCC diagnostic push/pop` doesn't work here. For a macro like `#define FOO 42`, embracing it in an expression statement ( `({ 42; })` ) would do the trick but that would prevent the macro from being used in contexts where an Integer Constant Expression is required (such as the `enum` definition))

Comment: I don't think you can do it in the macro itself, since some callers use the result. Maybe you can write `(void)STC_ASSERT(1, "");` in `main()`.

Comment: Clang [doesn't](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oGw0XHUxQ7Nz8nNf) generate a warning (if someone can be inspired by this and help OP with GCC). @Barmar's suggestion doesn't generate a warning in GCC.

Comment: @Barmar I don't doubt that. It's the reason the question says "inside the STC_ASSERT _Static_assert wrapper".  I've basically given up on -Wunused-result with clang after encountering this https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39367. If I can't make this example work with gcc, then I'm giving up on it on gcc too. I like the warning, but outside of functions expl. marked with the warn_unused_result attribute, it seems to lack a clear concept regarding where it should be generated, how it can be elicited (e.g., for macros based on expr. statements) and how it can be suppressed (e.g., here)).

Comment: sorry, but a side question. You use `!!sizeof(struct{char STC_ASSERT;...})` in your `STC_ASSERT` to create a 0 or 1 result from your assert function? Cannot find any other reason for it.

Comment: gcc 8.2 tells me it's `-Wunused-value` not -Wunused-result

Comment: @Afshin The idea is to turn `_Static_assert` into an expression so it can be used like it is in `C` (thereby tightly coupling the static assertion with the macro definition) while keeping `C` an integer constant expression (so it can be used, e.g., to define the `c` enumerator constant).

Comment: Could you define two macros, one intended to be used as an expression, the other as a statement?

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks for noticing. It should have said -Wunused-value (it does now).

Comment: sidenote: you can shorten this macro with an unnamed bitfield. `sizeof(struct { int :1; _Static_assert((X), Msg "" ); })`. Also `BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO` also generates this warning. Anyway, I would go with two macros - that's why in kernel thers `BUILD_BUG_ON` with `((void)sizeof(...))` and `BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO` which is evaulated in expression.

Comment: But I still don't get why you need to turn `_Static_assert` into expression. Because if assert happens, code will not compile (static assert), and if not, you will always have 1 as `C`. So I still cannot understand need of converting `_Static_assert` into expression. or I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks! I love the unnamed bitfield idea.

Comment: @Afshin It's about tightly coupling the static assertion with the definition of a value macro (the `C` macro in the code above) that possibly evaluates to an integer constant expression. I'm doing it mainly because if nicely fits into my error handling framework which somewhat resembles C++'s exceptions+RAII. In light of that you can sort of think of the C macro as `{ if(A<B) compile_time_throw; else return A-B; }`.

Comment: Aha, got it. Thanks a lot for info.